# Django - How to retain inline formset data in case of form_invalid()

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms, inline-formset

I'm trying to create a form to add new car advertisement using crispy_forms. It has a fieldset with ability to add car photos using django inline formset. It works well in case of form_valid - my ad creates successful, but in case of form_invalid(e.g. missed required field) I get my form back without uploaded images - images fieldset is cleaned. How can I retain formset data?
Here is my code:

models.py

```
class AdCar(CarEquipment, AdBase):
        """ Model of Car advertisements """
        car_brand = models.ForeignKey(CarBrand)
        car_model = models.ForeignKey(CarModel)
        launch_year = models.IntegerField(choices=LAUNCH_YEARS)
        state = models.IntegerField(choices=AUTO_STATE, default=None)
        ...

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(AdBase, related_name='images')
    src = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos")

    objects = ImageManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}{1}".format(MEDIA_URL, self.src)
```

forms.py

```
class AddCarAdvertForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddCarAdvertForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['steer'].required = False
        self.fields['electric_windows_lift'].required = False
        try:
            self.fields['car_model'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                queryset=CarModel.objects.filter(brand=self.initial['car_brand']),
                label = 'Model'
            )
        except KeyError:
            pass
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        # self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-xs-4'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-xs-8'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div('seller_city', css_class='col-xs-10 text-center', css_id='city_div'),
                Div(Div('car_brand', css_class='col-xs-6'), Div('car_model', css_class='col-xs-6',
                    css_id='car_model_div'))
    ...


class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.template = 'bootstrap/table_inline_formset.html'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('src'),
        )
        super(ImageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields = ('src',)


AdInlineFormSet = forms.models.inlineformset_factory(AdCar, ProductImage, form=ImageForm)
```

views.py

```
class AddCarAdvertView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'ads/car_advert_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ad_success')
    model = AdCar
    form_class = AddCarAdvertForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = {}
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            initial['seller_email'] = self.request.user.email
            initial['seller_name'] = self.request.user.first_name
        try:
            initial['seller_city'] = self.request.session['city_id']
        except KeyError:
            pass
        try:
            initial['car_brand'] = self.request.session['ad_car_brand']
        except KeyError:
            pass
        return initial

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        img_form = AdInlineFormSet()
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, img_form=img_form))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        img_form = AdInlineFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        if (form.is_valid() and img_form.is_valid()):
            return self.form_valid(form, img_form)
        else :
            return self.form_invalid(form, img_form)        

    def form_valid(self, form, img_form):
        self.object = form.save()
        img_form.instance = self.object
        img_form.save()


    def form_invalid(self, form, img_form):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, img_form=img_form))
```

template

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% crispy form %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#D93832">
                <h2 class="panel-title" style="font-size:1.2em">Photo block</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                {% crispy img_form img_form.form.helper %}
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center">
        <input id="submit-id-submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save">
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: When form is invalid, Django disregards uploaded images since it does not store them in any temporary way. If you absolutely need that feature, you will need to temporarily store the images somewhere on the server so that they can be reused within the same form. Not answering the question in case others already did something similar

Comment: Thanks for answer, at least I know that there is no default django solution

Comment: No problem. If you do figure this out, this would be a useful third-party library...